# Why is the Ohm's law $j=\sigma E$ accurate?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance

[Ohm's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) $j=\sigma\cdot E=\frac{Q}{A}\cdot \frac{F}{Q}=...?$

$$j=\rho\cdot v \\ =\frac{q}{V}\cdot \frac{s}{t}=\frac{1}{A}\cdot I$$

So why is $j=\sigma E$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$j=\sigma E$-This defines conductivity $\sigma$ for a material-it is the starting point.I think you are confused with signs.here $\sigma$ is conductivity and you are mixing it up with Surface charge density of electrostatics.So is the case for $\rho$.You are mixing it with volume charge density but it is actually resistivity here.

Note:This obviously is a very trivial issue and can be clarified from any book.So watch before asking such questions as these may attract negative reputation.

Comment: I don't see any requirement of the note. It's an honest question which a newbie might have.